# How to overwrite Table/Mapping in Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a `values.yaml` that has

```
ingress:
  enabled: false 

volume:
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

I have an `overlay.yaml` that changes the value of `values.yaml`.

```
ingress:
  enabled: true 

volume:
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: test
```

For the ingress, it's working as I suspected because the value of `enabled` will change to true. However, for the volume, it appears that tables add on to each other rather than get overwritten. For instance, I would get something like:

```
volume: 
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: test
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

I would like to specify a default volume type and its configurations (e.g. path) in values.yaml, but have the freedom for others to change this through an overlay. However, what I have now "adds" a volume type rather than overwrite it. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null` is [a specific valid YAML value](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/#id2803362) (the same as JSON `null`).  If you set a Helm value to `null`, then the Go `text/template` logic will unmarshal it to Go `nil` and it will appear as "false" in `if` statements and similar conditionals.

```yaml
volume:
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: test
  hostPath: null
```

I might avoid this problem in chart logic, though.  One approach would be to use a separate `type` field to say which sub-field you're looking for:

```yaml
# the chart's defaults in values.yaml
volume:
  type: HostPath
  hostPath: { ... }
```

```yaml
# your `helm install -f` overrides
volume:
  type: PersistentVolumeClaim
  persistentVolumeClaim: { ... }
  # (the default hostPath: will be present but unused)
```

A second option is to make the default "absent", and either disable the feature entirely or construct sensible defaults in the chart code if it's not present.

```yaml
# values.yaml

# volume specifies where the application will keep persistent data.
# If unset, each replica will have independent data and this data will
# be lost on restart.
#
# volume:
#
#  persistentVolumeClaim stores data in an existing PVC.
#
#  persistentVolumeClaim:
#    name: ???
```

```yaml
# deep in templates/deployment.yaml
volumes:
{{- if .Values.volume.persistentVolumeClaim }}
  - name: storage
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: {{ .Values.volume.persistentVolumeClaim.name }}
{{- else if .Values.volume.hostPath }}
  - name: storage
    hostPath:
      path: {{ .Values.volume.hostPath.path }}
{{- end }}
{{-/* (just don't create a volume if not set) */}}
```

Or, to always provide *some* kind of storage, even if it's not that useful:

```yaml
volumes:
  - name: storage
{{- if .Values.volume.persistentVolumeClaim }}
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: {{ .Values.volume.persistentVolumeClaim.name }}
{{- else if .Values.volume.hostPath }}
    hostPath:
      path: {{ .Values.volume.hostPath.path }}
{{- else }}
    emptyDir: {}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Right now, my implementation follows close to your second option. I was wondering if there were any other options available as this leads to some messy code in other parts of our codebase. I'll definitely try out the other approaches that you mentioned.